# Image SlideShow Custom Control in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, custom-controls

I am searching Image SlideShow Custom Control for iOS.

like following image

[image]

Comment: Do you mean [CoverFlow](https://github.com/H2CO3/OpenFlow)?

Comment: Is there any ready made sample code that used of CoverFlow.I got only Classes.

Comment: `[[AFCoverFlowView alloc] init]` is all what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). It looks nice, and it is easy to use.